# Can not resolve 'ST_GeomFromText' in serviceImpl class

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, geojson

I am trying to save my geometry data to MySQL table through JPA.

```
georepository.save("id", ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 1, 2 5, 2 7, 0 7, 0 1))') );
```

but I am getting:

> Can not resolve 'ST_GeomFromText' in serviceImpl class.

Here is my model

```
public class Mygeo {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private String id;

   @Column(name = "geodata", nullable = false)
   private Geometry geodata;
}
```

This is how I am saving manually in DB. what will be the JPA alternate way to save this.

```
INSERT INTO mygeo (id, geodata)VALUES ("ID",ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 1, 2 5, 2 7, 0 7, 0 1))'));
```

Note : I do have access of geometry string like this

```
System.out.println(geometryObject.toString());
{"coordinates":[[[0,1],[2,5],[2,7],[0,7],[0,1]]],"type":"Polygon"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to save the Geometry data into database while using the Spring Data JPA is given below in details (step - by - step):

---

I will explain with the help of a project.

The project structure :

[image]

MyGeo entity :

```
package com.solve.problemssolve;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
public class MyGeo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "geodata", nullable = false)
    private Geometry geodata;
}
```

MyGeoRepository class

```
package com.solve.problemssolve;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface MyGeoRepository extends JpaRepository<MyGeo, String> {

}
```

application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Anish@123
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL5SpatialDialect
```

**Note:** You have to enable `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL5SpatialDialect` in your spring boot application to support spatial features.

According to [MySQL5SpatialDialect Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/spatial/dialect/mysql/MySQL5SpatialDialect.html) :

> It is a dialect for MySQL 5 using InnoDB engine, with support for its
> spatial features.

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.solve</groupId>
    <artifactId>problems-solve</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>problems-solve</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In MySQL DB (Table structure) :

[image]

**Note:** This table is automatically generated by Hibernate as I have kept `ddl-auto=update` but you can create table manually also.

Resource class :

```
@RestController
public class Resource {

    @Autowired
    private MyGeoRepository myGeoRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/save")
    public void save() throws ParseException {
        WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader();
        Geometry geometry = wktReader.read("POLYGON((0 1, 2 5, 2 7, 0 7, 0 1))");
        System.out.println(geometry);
        MyGeo geo = new MyGeo();
        geo.setGeodata(geometry);
        geo.setId("ID");
        myGeoRepository.save(geo); 
        System.out.println(myGeoRepository.findById("ID"));
    }
        
}
```

You have to use `WKTReader` to save the data via JPA.

According to [WKTReader](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/io/WKTReader.html) docs :

> Converts a geometry in Well-Known Text format to a Geometry.
>
> WKTReader supports extracting Geometry objects from either Readers or
> Strings. This allows it to function as a parser to read Geometry
> objects from text blocks embedded in other data formats (e.g. XML).
>
> A WKTReader is parameterized by a GeometryFactory, to allow it to
> create Geometry objects of the appropriate implementation. In
> particular, the GeometryFactory determines the PrecisionModel and SRID
> that is used.
>
> The WKTReader converts all input numbers to the precise internal
> representation.

According to [WKTReader.read(String wellKnownText)](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/io/WKTReader.html#read-java.io.Reader-) docs :

> It reads a Well-Known Text representation of a Geometry from a String.

This SQL statement `ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 1, 2 5, 2 7, 0 7, 0 1))')` is equivalent to this line `Geometry geometry = wktReader.read("POLYGON((0 1, 2 5, 2 7, 0 7, 0 1))");`

As soon as, I have ran the example, it saved successfully without any issues.

Server log screenshot :

[image]

DB row screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anish B. worked like charm. Lot of help and new this to learn,